# Access javascript object outside pug file

Tags: javascript, file, pug, external

I am trying to use Pug to generate a datalist based on data from another .js file. My problem is figuring out how to get Pug to read this javascript object

I currently have a wizardSpells.js file withe the following data:

```
// wizardSpells.js
const wiz1 = {};
wiz1['Affect Normal Fires'] = {'school': 'Alteration'};
wiz1['Alarm'] = {'school': 'Abjuration, Evocation'};
wiz1['Armor'] = {'school': 'Conjuration'};
```

Here is the content of my datalist.pug file:

```
//datalist.pug
datalist(id='wiz1-spells')
  each val, key in wiz1  
    option(value=val.school) key
```

The error I get when I try to compile the pug file into HTML is the following:

```
TypeError: .\pug\datalists.pug:2
  1| datalist(id='wiz1-spells')
> 2|   each val, key in wiz1
  3|     option(value=val.school) key

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

My problem clearly is that my javascript object is undefined in the datalist.pug file.

**How do I get Pug to access my javascript file and the javascript object?**
I would **highly** prefer a solution that does not edit the wizardSpells.js file, and keep all changes within the datalists.pug file.

---

**Additional info**

- Pug has been installed via Node with `npm install pug-cli`
- I generate my html via the pug-cli with the following command: `pug .\pug\datalists.pug -o ./html -P`

I have all the files locally available on my machine so no network or big setup is necessary. All I need Pug to do, is to read the local file and use it for generating output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to export the object from `wizardSpells.js` to be able to access it.

```js
// wizardSpells.js
const wiz1 = {};
wiz1['Affect Normal Fires'] = {'school': 'Alteration'};
wiz1['Alarm'] = {'school': 'Abjuration, Evocation'};
wiz1['Armor'] = {'school': 'Conjuration'};
module.exports = { wiz1 };
```

Alternatively, don't use the `pug-cli` package, use the `pug` package instead and generate the HTML output from NodeJS directly.

```js
// build.js
const pug = require('pug');
const wizardSpells = require('./wizardSpells.js');
const html = pug.renderFile('datalist.pug', wizardSpells);
console.log(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the answer above I managed to make it work. My final setup looks like this:

```
// wizardSpells.js
const wiz1 = {};
wiz1['Affect Normal Fires'] = {'school': 'Alteration'};
wiz1['Alarm'] = {'school': 'Abjuration, Evocation'};
wiz1['Armor'] = {'school': 'Conjuration'};
module.exports = wiz1;
```

The javascript `wiz1` object is exported directly without any wrapper object.

```
// build.js
const pug = require('pug');
const fs = require('fs');
const wiz1= require('./wizardSpells.js');
const html = pug.renderFile('../src/datalist.pug', {pretty: true, wiz1: wiz1});
fs.writeFileSync('datalist.html', html);
```

I had to install Pug locally in my project, `npm install pug` (note no -g flag) to get the `require()` function to work.

I send the `wiz1` object to pug in the `pug.renderFile()` line, but it seems that pug is unable to serve the "root object" for iteration, and only the properties of the root object can be accessed. Therefore I wrap the `wiz1` object in another object, and also add the `pretty: true` flag to get nicely indented HTML.

This now allows me to access the `wiz1` object in my pug file:

```
// datalist.pug
datalist(id='wiz1-spells')
  each val, key in wiz1
    option(value=val.school)= key
```

To run everything I use the following command: `node build.js`

The final HTML looks like this:

```
<datalist id="wiz1-spells">
  <option value="Alteration">Affect Normal Fires</option>
  <option value="Abjuration, Evocation">Alarm</option>
  <option value="Conjuration">Armor</option>
</datalist>
```

---

**Note:** As I also use the `wizardSpells.js` as content for my final HTML, I have a post processing step that removes the `module.export` line, before insertion, to avoid it breaking the javascript when it is added to the HTML and loaded by the browser.

Comment: The `require('pug')` results in needing to have pug installed locally, it didn't recognize globally installed package that way.